# Compile java using Apache ANT

Tags: java, ant, build

How to compile java project using Apache ANT with the JRE system libraries and other libraries i have.
The code i am using is

```
<path id="master-classpath">
    <fileset dir="junit">
        <include name="*.jar"/>
    </fileset>
    <pathelement path="${build.dir}"/>
</path> 

<target name="build" description="Compile source tree java files">

    <mkdir dir="${build.dir}"/>
    <javac destdir="${build.dir}" source="1.5" target="1.5" includeantruntime="false">
        <src path="${src.dir}"/>
    <classpath refid="master-classpath"/>
    </javac>
</target>
```

its only taking the jar files in the junit folder.
I dont know how to compile with JRE system libraries.

Comment: you need to check following link. http://balusc.blogspot.in/2007/03/post-redirect-get-pattern.html

Comment: The JRE system libraries are automatically in the classpath. You don't need to do anything to have them included. What's the problem?

Comment: If you are getting any symbol not found error, please post it into the question.  error is most likely coming from another library , not from jdk libraries.